# GCM(Google Cloud Messaging ) in iOS( notification and data payload.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a question.For iOS,Can we send both "data" and "notification" in the payload?I was getting the notification when only "notification" was sent to the GCM.When I added both,I am not getting any notification.My question is,What should be the payload if I want to get update on both iOS and android devices?

current payload :

```
    {
    "to":"/topics/testTopic",
    "content_available":true,
    "priority":"high",
    "notification": {
                    "body":"Test Message",
                   "title":"test"
                    }, 
    "data": { 
                   "title": "Title.D Mixed JSON", 
                    "body": "Content.D Mixed JSON", 
              "productId" : "1" 
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your payload is fine, there is no reason that you should not be getting it. But there are some differences between those two.
Difference between `"notification"` and `"data"` is documented in official documentation: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

> Use notifications when you want GCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app’s behalf. Use data messages when you want your app to handle the display or process the messages on your Android client app, or if you want to send messages to iOS devices when there is a direct GCM connection

So, for you hybrid messages that you want to send it is important to know if your app is in the background or in the foreground:

> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.
>   When in the foreground, your app receives a bundle with both payloads available.

Another reason for not receiving push notifications is that you have not assigned delivery priority. There are two options `normal` and `high`.

**High**

> High priority. GCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the GCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a network connection to your app server

**Normal**

> Normal priority. This is the default priority for message delivery. Normal priority messages won't open network connections on a sleeping device, and their delivery may be delayed to conserve battery

Try to set `"priority" : "high"` right before `"notification"` in your payload.

Comment: That was just a sample payload before.I have edited the question with the actual payload that I am using.Check it.

Comment: Why is your "data" inside "notification"? "Notification" has it's parameters described here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref and "data" is not one of them. You must use "data" outside "notification" for accessing it.

Comment: Data is outside notification.See the payload syntax without data json string will work fine.But when it is data alone or data and notification,it will not work.

Comment: Please try to change name of you keys in "data" payload, to some custom string keys, try not to use already defined keys for parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Allowed to duplicate the content of "notification" and "data", you can read the data inside the "notification" when the user tap on the notification, the following JSON should work with you.

```
 {
   "to":"/topics/testTopic",
   "content_available":true,
   "priority":"high",
   "notification": {
             "body":"Test Message",
             "title":"test"
           }, 
   "data": { 
             "productId" : "1" 
           } 
}
```